# Thread Safe singleton in C++ using static member instance (no lazy instantiation)

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

I am aware of the Meyers singleton:

```
class Singleton{
private:
    Singleton();

public:
    Singleton & GetInstance(){
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The advantages of it is that it uses lazy evaluation but it is not guaranteed to be thread-safe in C++ 03.

What if the static instance is a member variable? Is that guaranteed to be thread-safe? I don't see why not. Moreover I'm willing to give up the lazy instantiation for that.

```
class Singleton{
private:
    Singleton();
    static Singleton instance;

public:
    Singleton & GetInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe have a look at this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744811/global-variables-in-modern-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the singleton instance to be a static class member, the creation of that instance will be thread safe. Whatever you do with it, will of cause still need to be protected in many cases.

Also see [When are static C++ class members initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421671/when-are-static-c-class-members-initialized)

Answer (score 1):

That just defeats the singleton altogether. Yes, it becomes thread-safe. But now it is the same as simply global variable of type `Singleton`, so why go for that extra typing of `Instance()` and friends?

Answer (score 1):

While you gain thread-safety, you do not defeat the "static initialization order fiasco" any more, which is in my oppinion the most important aspect of this type of Singleton class.